# pyspark: filtering rows by length of inside values

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with a column contains Python list

```
id value
1 [1,2,3]
2 [1,2]
```

I want to remove all rows with `len` of the list in `value` column is less than 3.

So I tried:

`df.filter(len(df.value) >= 3)`

and indeed it does not work.

How can I filter the dataframe by the length of the inside data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) -

`size()` - It returns the length of the array or map stored in the column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size
myValues = [(1,[1,2,3]),(2,[1,2])]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['id','value'])
df.show()
+----+---------+
|  id|    value|
+--------------+
|   1|  [1,2,3]|
|   2|    [1,2]|
+----+---------+
df = df.filter(size(df.value) >= 3).show()
+----+---------+
|  id|    value|
+--------------+
|   1|  [1,2,3]|
+----+---------+
```